# Unable to validate if a string is null or not in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab-ci

I'm making curl call in my shell script which is successful and then I try to validate if the `$JIRA_DESCRIPTION` is null or not in response that received from API call by using following code:-

```
- export JIRA_DESCRIPTION=$(echo ${JIRA_DETAIL} | jq '.fields.description')
- |
  if [[ "$JIRA_DESCRIPTION" = null ]]
    then 
      echo "FAILED! Jira description cannot be empty"; exit 1
    else 
      echo "PASSED! Jira description check"; echo $?
  fi
```

This check is failing every time and I get passed condition even if the string is empty. IfI try to print using echo the value of jira_description variable then I just get double quotes with no space in between `""`. What is wrong with my code? How to fix this?

Full source code is here:-

```
validate-jira:
  image: python:3.9
  variables:
    JIRA_HEADER: 'Accept: application/json'
    UNACCEPTED_JIRA_STATUSES: "Done, Completed, Closed"
  script:
    # extract the JIRA id out of the Merge Request title.
    # The following logic assumes a Merge Request title must start with a valid JIRA issue id and that all JIRA projects start with a letter
    - export MERGE_REQUEST_JIRA_ID=$(echo ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE} | sed 's/\([0-9]\):.*$/\1/')

    # Validate if we had successfully extracted a Jira Issue Id
    - |
      if test -z "$(echo "$MERGE_REQUEST_JIRA_ID" | sed "/^${JIRA_PROJECT_CODE}-/d")"
       then 
         echo "Jira Id found in the Merge Request title!"; echo $?
       else   
         echo "Either Jira Id not found in the Merge Request title or it is invalid (should start with ${JIRA_PROJECT_CODE}-)!"; exit 1
      fi

    # Make API Call to get the JIRA Details
    - export JIRA_DETAIL=$(curl -u ${JIRA_USERNAME}:${JIRA_PASSWORD} -H "${JIRA_HEADER}" -X GET "https://${JIRA_SERVER}/rest/api/2/issue/${MERGE_REQUEST_JIRA_ID}?fields=description&fields=status&fields=customfield_11000&fields=customfield_15700")

    # extract the JIRA key id, this also validates JIRA issue referenced is valid
    - export JIRA_KEY_ID=$(echo ${JIRA_DETAIL} | jq -e '.key')

    # extract the JIRA status
    - export JIRA_STATUS=$(echo ${JIRA_DETAIL} | jq '.fields.status.name')    

    # To bypass Jira validation check in case if Jira server is down. simply exit the job with 'success' status
    - |
      if [[ "${JIRA_CASE_ID_VALIDATION}" = 0 ]] 
        then             
          echo "Bypassing Jira validation check. Exiting with success status..."; exit 0  
      fi

    # Check the Jira status from server response
    - |
      if [[ "$JIRA_STATUS" = null ]] 
        then             
          echo "Unable to retrieve the Jira details from server, exiting the job!"; exit 1  
      fi

    # optionally test status of the JIRA issue matches a desired "status"
    - |
      JIRA_STATUS_TO_COPY_FROM=$(echo $UNACCEPTED_JIRA_STATUSES | sed -e 's/\s*,\s*/|/g')
      echo $JIRA_STATUS_TO_COPY_FROM
      if test -z "$(echo ${JIRA_STATUS} | sed -r "s/\"($JIRA_STATUS_TO_COPY_FROM)\"//")"
        then 
          echo "FAILED! Not a valid Jira (Done/Completed/Closed)"; exit 1
        else 
          echo "PASSED! Jira status check"; echo $?
      fi

    # extract the Jira Description
    - export JIRA_DESCRIPTION=$(echo ${JIRA_DETAIL} | jq '.fields.description')
    # Validate if Jira description is null or not
    - |
      echo $JIRA_DESCRIPTION
      echo 'doneeee'
      if [ -z  "$JIRA_DESCRIPTION" ]
        then 
          echo "FAILED! Jira description cannot be empty"; exit 1
        else 
          echo "PASSED! Jira description check"; echo $?
      fi
```

**Output on GitLab CI Job:-**

```
$ export JIRA_DESCRIPTION=$(echo ${JIRA_DETAIL} | jq '.fields.description')
$ echo $JIRA_DESCRIPTION # collapsed multi-line command
""
doneeee
PASSED! Jira description check
```

Comment: `= null` is not a thing. Use `[[ -z  "$JIRA_DESCRIPTION" ]]`

Comment: it is not working, still passing.... $ export JIRA_DESCRIPTION=$(echo ${JIRA_DETAIL} | jq '.fields.description')
$ if [[ -z  "$JIRA_DESCRIPTION" ]] # collapsed multi-line command
PASSED! Jira description check

Comment: if I hit the URL using postman then I can confirm that description is empty... like {
    "expand": "renderedFields,names,schema,operations,editmeta,changelog,versionedRepresentations",
    "id": "360880",
    "key": "JDD-2334",
    "fields": {
        "description": "",

Comment: [edit] your question to show minimal representative contents of `JIRA_DETAIL` so we can help you.

Comment: Why do the first 2 lines of your script each start with a `-` character and why is there a `|` character on line 2?

Comment: this script is written in GitLab's CI file....let me edit the question

Comment: You say `I try to print using echo the value of jira_description variable then I just get double quotes with no space in between ""` - that means that the jira_description variable contains a pair of double quotes, it isn't empty. Try `if [[ "$JIRA_DESCRIPTION" = '""' ]]` or similar.

Comment: Your script has several other issues, you should copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net so it can tell you about some of those but you'll need to strip all that gitlab Ci (whatever that is!) stuff first to get it to just be a shell script.

Comment: `jq` surrounds string fields in quotes in its output by default. You can use `jq -r` to disable this and have it write the strings to stdout without the quotes and then the variable will actually be empty.

Comment: yeah @tjm3772 it was doing that exactly....

Comment: @EdMorton this worked if [[ "$JIRA_DESCRIPTION" = '""' ]]

Comment: You did not show the content of `JIRA_DESCRIPTION`.  Do a `xxd <<<$JIRA_DESCRIPTION`, so that you can see exactly what's in this variable.

Comment: @tjm3772 thanks, as suggested I added -r flag with jq and it worked like expected.....thanks everyone...really appreciated

Comment: `jq -re 'if (.fields.description) then .fields.description+"\ndoneeee\nPASSED! Jira description check" else ("donneeee\nFAILED! Jira description cannot be empty", null) end' <<< "${JIRA_DETAIL}"` Only with jq

Answer (score 1):

There's no such concept as 'null' in shell scripts.

You're comparing the returned string to the literal 4-character string `null`, which will (probably) always be false.  You want to compare against an actual empty string

```
if [[ "$JIRA_DESCRIPTION" == "" ]]
```

or alternately use the `-z` test for a zero-length string

```
if [[ -z "$JIRA_DESCRIPTION" ]]
```